# How can I send messages to Chromecast from other activity

Tags: android, android-activity, message, chromecast, sender

I would like to know how can I send messages to Chromecast from other activity in my sender.

I have two activities, the first one do the connection with Chromecast and is able to send messages and communicate succesfully with it, but I want to send messages to Chromecast from the second activity too.

When I do this, calling the "sendMessage" method the variables "selectedDevice" (CastDevice) and "apiClient" (GoogleApiClient) are null, anyone could tell me what is the best way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Create a static class where you have references to these items all the time, until the connection is removed

Comment: ¿Could you show me an small example or something? I don't understand what do you refer with a static class, thank you

Comment: Ok, I could solve it storing both variables with static access in a class. Thank you